# Backbone child view and parent view is not working simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone. When I tried to render both parent and child view simultaneously, only parent view got rendered! I want to know why this is happening and what are the other methods to accomplish this?

**childView.js:**

```
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#foo').html()),
  initialize: function() {
  },
  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
    return this;
  }
});
```

**parentView.js:**

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('body'),
  initialize: function() {
    this.childView = new ChildView();
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get('templates/parentView.html', function(data) {
      template = _.template(data, {});
      self.$el.html(template);
    }, 'html');
    $('#main').html(this.childView.render().el);
  },
});
var parentView = new ParentView();
```

**parentView.html:**

```
<header>
  <h1>This is header</h1>
</header>
<main id="main">

</main>
<footer>
  <p>This is footer</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of improvement that could be made, here's a few:

- It's unnecessary to use the jQuery global selector, use [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) for the view's element, or [`this.$()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) for a scoped jQuery search.
- [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) takes a string or a DOM element, not a jQuery object.
- `render` should be idempotent and fast, don't fetch the template each time.
- `.html()` function is a little heavier than just `.empty().append()`.
- You can pass a context to the `.get()` (success) callbacks.
- Use [`.setElement()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) when you want to assign a view to an existing element.

## ChildView

```
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#foo').html()),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty().append(this.template({}));
        return this;
    }
});
```

## ParentView

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    initialize: function() {
        this.childView = new ChildView();

        $.get({
            url: 'templates/parentView.html',
            success: this.onTemplateLoad,
            context: this,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty().append(this.template({ /** data */ }));

        this.childView.setElement(this.$('#main'));

        return this;
    },

    onTemplateLoad: function(data) {
        this.template = _.template(data, {});
        this.render();
    }

});
```

## Instanciate

```
var parentView = new ParentView();
```

Comment: @MuneebPullani please be more specific.

Comment: when I mix both answers, it works. Unless it is not!

Comment: @MuneebPullani While the other answer explains why your code doesn't work, mine shows how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

In the parent view `render` function, child view `el` is assigned to `$('#main')` but by then it is not on the DOM as the parent view `el` is not attached to DOM, you can make the below change to assign child view html to parent view `el`.

```
this.$el.find('#main').html(this.childView.render().el);
$(body).html(this.$el);
```

`$("#main")` searches for element on the DOM, `this.$el.find("#main")` searches for element in the `this.$el` element descendants.

Comment: Is that $.get() jQuery function will not set parentView to DOM?